# $C_0^\infty(\mathbb{R}^k)$ functions can be approximated via polynomials

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, functions, weierstrass-approximation

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^k\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a vanishing at infinity function, also infinitely differentiable, i.e. $f\in C_0^\infty(\mathbb{R}^k,\mathbb{R})$. Is it true that I can always approximate $f$ with some polynomial $p$? Can I use here directly the right version of the Stone-Weierstrass theorem considering the subalgebra of polynomials $P:=\lbrace p:\mathbb{R}^k\rightarrow \mathbb{R} \mid p \text{ polynomial} \rbrace$?

Answer (score 5):

If you're interested in uniform convergence of polynomials on all of $\mathbb R^k,$ there's not much good news: The only $f\in C_0^\infty$ that can be uniformly approximated by polynomials is the zero function. That's because if $P$ is a polynomial, then either $P$ is a constant or $P$ is unbounded.

Comment: I think then that the unique way to approximate a function $f\in C_0^\infty$ is by means of Taylor polynomials by defining $p_n(x)=\sum_{i=0}^n \frac{f^{(i)}(0)}{i!}x^i$. Then $p_n\rightarrow f$ pointwise, but I guess not uniformly at this point....

Comment: In this case one should also have that the derivatives of $p_n$ tend to the f ones, i.e.  $p_n^{(j)}\rightarrow f^{(j)}$ pointwise for all $j\in \mathbb{N}$....

Comment: @stochastic_name_here  On your first comment, recall that the Taylor series for a smooth function $f$ need not equal $f$ anywhere except the base point. For example, in $\mathbb R^1$ we have the example $f(x)=\exp(-1/x^2).$

Comment: I previously wrote "The natural norm on $C_0^\infty(\mathbb{R}^k,\mathbb{R})$ is the $\sup$-norm." That's obviously wrong. So I changed my answer to the above.

Answer (score 2):

Yes and no.

If you restrain $f$ to take a compact domain $C \subseteq \mathbb{R}^k$, then the answer is an unambiguous yes. For the Stone-Weirstrass theorem only requires an algebra of functions which can discriminate between points, and this clearly applies to polynomials in $k$ variables.

If you wish to distinguish between points $(x_1, ..., x_k)$ and $(y_1, ..., y_k)$, just take the polynomial $P(z_1, ..., z_n) = \sum\limits_{i = 1}^n (z_i - x_i)^2$.

If you do not restrict $f$ to have a compact domain, you can still construct a sequence of polynomials which converges pointwise to $f$ (but not necessarily uniformly). This is true even if $k = 1$; take $f(x) = e^x$, for example.

Comment: Thank you! I notice here that $C_c^\infty(\mathbb{R}^k,\mathbb{R})$ is dense in $C_0^\infty(\mathbb{R}^k,\mathbb{R})$. Thus taking $f_n\in C_c^\infty(\mathbb{R}^k,\mathbb{R})$ converging to $f\in C_0^\infty(\mathbb{R}^k,\mathbb{R})$ one can approximate each $f_n$ with a polynomial and thus also $f$ can be approximated via polynomials. However I am not fully satisfied by the answer. Are the conditions for the locally compact version of the Stone-Weirestrass theorem fully satisfied by $P$ (i.e. P a subalgebra of  $C_0^\infty(\mathbb{R}^k,\mathbb{R})$, separates the points vanishing nowhere)?

Comment: @stochastic_name_here The locally compact Stone-Weierstrass theorem requires the algebra of functions to vanish at infinity. Polynomials do not vanish at infinity (except for the zero polynomial).

Comment: Thank you! I can see the problem now! So I can get pointwise convergence...

Comment: @stochastic_name_here Yes, pointwise is the best you can do in general (as the example of $e^x$ shows, where for all polynomials $P$, $\sup e^x - P(x) = \infty)$.